# Create many to many Relationship with a specific fields in a Content type to taxonomy

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am currently encounter a problem, I have one content type (Type) and two taxonomy needed to be link up, in that content type, I need to apply a many to many relationship among a field (Name: Core) and two taxonomy Terms (Such like below image), I would like to ask is there any method to implement this idea??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [entity_reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).

- Add a field "Core" to your content type of entity reference.
- Then under "target type", choose "taxonomy term"
- Under "entity selection" choose your vocabularies
- On the next page set "Number of values" to "unlimited"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have already add two fields of term reference to store two taxonomy term, for the field "Core", It will be a boolean, what I mean is there any method to link up these two term reference fields and boolean field(Core) with m-m relationship?? Thanks

Comment: I think you will have to setup your content type like I suggested. I don't think you will be able to solve your problem with your current structure

Comment: Ok, let me know if this fixes your problem :).

Comment: I have updated it, I create a entity reference field (Name : Core) to link up two taxonomy, but I still very confuse on the next step, may be I tell you the whole situation on next answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the original idea (not yea update by the entity reference)

I have one content type call Title, in this content type, there will be a field name "Core
 (boolean type), and there are two taxonomy term name Subject and Type, these three will be a M to M relationship, the problem is not all the selected Subject/Type can be "Core" item (e.g You can select Subject A,B,C and Type H,L, but you can set only Subject A and Type H to be Core), so I still no idea how to get next even I set the Core to entity reference and link to two taxonomy term, do you have any idea on this?? Many Thanks

[image]